# Center Placeholder in Input Field

Tags: html, css, input, center, placeholder

The placeholder in my `input` element has a space on top and bottom of it, I want to remove that spacing so that my placeholder will be centered to the top and bottom of my element, I've tried:
`line-height: 0, vertical-align` etc and it hasn't made a difference.

I'm testing it in Chrome (view in full page)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

.call-back-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}


#call_back {
    background: #383E46 0% 0% no-repeat border-box;
    border: none;
    color: #F4A95080;
    padding-left: 27px;
padding-top: 18px;
padding-bottom: 18px;
min-width: clamp(9.615rem, 10.732vw + 2.746rem, 15.625rem);

}

input[id^="call_back"]:focus {
    outline: none;
    color: #F4A95080;

        cursor: auto;
}

input:focus[id^="call_back"]::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

#call_back::placeholder {
    text-align: left;
font: normal normal normal clamp(0.654rem, 0.73vw + 0.187rem, 1.063rem)Poppins;
color: #F4A95080;
opacity: 1;
}


.submitBtn {
    text-align: left;
font: normal normal normal clamp(0.615rem, 0.688vw + 0.175rem, 1rem)Poppins;
letter-spacing: 0px;
color: #383E46;
background: #F4A950 0% 0% no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
border: none;
}

.submitBtn:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="myemailform" class="call-back-wrapper"action="form-to-email.php">
                <input type="tel" id="call_back" name="call_back"
                  placeholder="Phone Number" onkeypress="return onlyNumberKey(event)" required />
                  <button class="submitBtn">Call Back</button>
              </form>
```

Image of how I want it to look
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qJbH.png
Reference on how it appears in my code, highlighted in chrome(you can see the extra space on the top and bottom of placeholder
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P4aF.png
Reference Image of how it appears in chrome
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMKa1.png
Without padding top or bottom it still has a space:  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gchm5.png

Comment: Try setting `padding:0` and `height` should be less

Comment: @Azu on what should I set the padding? on the placeholder?

Comment: It does look vertically centered. If you want to remove the space, remove `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` from `#call_back`

Comment: @drak that doesn't make a difference to it, it has an extra space on the bottom of the placeholder regardless if i remove the padding, view it in full screen to see what I'm referring to

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not seeing any extra space after removing the padding in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfbavjd1/). Maybe add a screenshot to your question, to show what effect you want to achieve.

Comment: @drak I added images for reference

Comment: @wondering you are checking in which browser ?

Comment: @Suresh in chrome

Comment: then try this css input[type="tel"]::placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this piece of CSS.

```
input[type="tel"]::placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

to your first line of your css

Comment: This rule is too general and by adding it you risk to change those styles for the other HTML items.

Comment: I already have this set, it doesn't make a difference

Comment: because you have padding-bottom and top:18px; in #call_back , remove them @wondering

Comment: you are right bro, that's why i said add it to your first line, thanks for the head up too <3 @Azu

Comment: @ArmanMoalemi without padding top and bottom it also has a space, I added an image for reference

Comment: try align-items:center; for .call-back-wrapper @wondering

Answer (score 0):

just use a text-align in your input (remembering to put the type in the input and the colon for placeholder)

```
input[type="tel"]::placeholder { text-align: center;}
```